# How to prevent changing of the IP address from Memgraph Cloud instance?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've noticed when pausing and restarting an instance on Memgraph Cloud the IP address of my instance changes. This means that I have to change my connection details in Memgraph Lab each time after the unpausing the instance.[Cloud dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vniGt.png)

Can I somehow get the IP without logging into Cloud dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expected behavior. The reason for this is because of the way that cloud providers, like AWS where Memgraph Cloud is located, manage resources. They are allocated dynamically to optimize efficiency, so every time you pause an instance resources are released. This includes IP address. My trick is to update local `.hosts` file after I reactivate the instance. That way I have a `hostname` that I can use instead of IP address.